# check overflow when multiply with 3 by bitwise

Tags: overflow, bit-manipulation

I have problem how to solve this one, Iam thinking about return
int product = 3 * n;
return (!n || product/n == 3);
however, I cant use those operators.

```
    /*
     *  Overflow detection of 3*n 
     *    Input is positive
     *    Example:  overflow( 10 ) = 0
     *    Example:  overlfow( 1<<30 ) = 1
     *    Legal ops:  & | >> << ~
     *    Max ops:  10
     *
     *    Number of X86 instructions:
     */
     int overflow_3( int n ) {

     return 2;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition is equivalent to checking whether x is larger than MAX_INT / 3, that is, x > 0x2aaaaaaa. Since x is known to be nonnegative, we know that the top bit is zero and thus we can check the condition as follows:

```
unsigned overflow(unsigned x) {
  return (x + 0x55555555) >> 31;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible options for a number to overflow when multiplied by 3.
Let's look at X3 multiplication. There are two actions: 
 1. Shift left by 1 leaves the leftmost bit set. This could only happen if the near leftmost (i.e the 30) bit is set 
 2. Shift left by 1 leaves the leftmost bit unset. However the following addition of the original number results in having the bits set. This could only happen if the 29 bit is set (since it is the only one that will become the 30 after the shift) and if either the 28 or the 27 bit is set (since they can overflow to the 30 bit). However the 27 but by itself being set is not enough (since we need the 26 bit to be set, or the 25th and 24th) and etc.

So basically you need a loop here. However since loops are not allowed I would use recursion. So:

```
    int overflow_3(int n){
     return n >> 30 || (n >> 29 && overflow_3( (n & ( (1 << 29) - 1)) << 2 ) );
   }
```

Comment: Thanks!I'm sorry, but we can't use recursion as well, and "-" is not a legal operator. And if we use recursion, the operation will be greater than max ops, which is 10.

Comment: (1 << 29) - 1 is a constant. You can use 0x1fffffff instead.